# Call flow explanation

Tags: sip

In the book "Understanding SIP" they say that  only for responses for INVITE an ACK is sent, but in this call flow there is ACK for BYE also.

Can someone please explain this phenomenon to me?

[image: Call Flow]]

[image: Description in book]]

Comment: First, finish reading the chapter. Then check the book's errata. Finally, read the relevant RFC(s).

Answer (score 1):

The call flow diagram is incorrect. Responses to BYE should be 2xx; ACK are only used to acknowledge responses to INVITE as mentioned. See [RFC 3261](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261) for more details.

> At the end of the call, Bob disconnects (hangs up) first and
> generates a BYE message.  This BYE is routed directly to Alice's
> softphone, again bypassing the proxies.  Alice confirms receipt of
> the BYE with a 200 (OK) response, which terminates the session and
> the BYE transaction.  No ACK is sent - an ACK is only sent in
> response to a response to an INVITE request.  The reasons for this
> special handling for INVITE will be discussed later, but relate to
> the reliability mechanisms in SIP, the length of time it can take for
> a ringing phone to be answered, and forking.  For this reason,
> request handling in SIP is often classified as either INVITE or non-
> INVITE, referring to all other methods besides INVITE.  Full details
> on session termination are in Section 15.